# Pandas Where 2 Columns Match, but Another Column Does Not

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've had a problem I've been trying to solve using pandas, but it's been vexing me for a couple of days now. I have 2 dataframes:

```
data = {'GMC1':[1, 3, 5, 5, 8, 9, 8, 13],
        'Provider1':[101, 102, 103, 150, 160, 450, 567, 230]}

dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
data2 = {'GMC2':[1, 5, 7, 22, 11, 13, 9, 8],
         'Provider2':[101, 150, 150, 670, 567, 230, 340, np.nan]}

dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

This is a little tricky to describe, but I would like a dataframe returned where:

- Provider1 is not in provider2, where the GMC1 and GMC2 match
- If Provider2 is NaN, then count it as not matching Provider1

So, for the example data:

```
mergeDF = pd.merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, how = 'inner', left_on = 'GMC1', right_on = 'GMC2')

mergeDF = mergeDF[['GMC1', 'GMC2', 'Provider1', 'Provider2']]
```

| GMC1 | GCM2 | Provider1 | Provider2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 101 | 101 |
| 5 | 5 | 103 | 150 |
| 5 | 5 | 150 | 150 |
| 8 | 8 | 160 | NaN |
| 8 | 8 | 567 | NaN |
| 9 | 9 | 450 | 340 |
| 13 | 13 | 230 | 230 |

- For GMC = 1, I would not want anything returned, because both the gmc and the provider values match.
- For GMC = 5, I would only want the row where provider1 = 103, because there is another row where GMC = 5 where both provider1 and provider2 have the value of 150.
- Return rows where GMC = 8 and 9, because there are not corresponding values in Provider2

I have tried merging as above on GMC, and then merging again on the provider1 and provider2 columns, but I can't get the output I want. I also tried using the isin() function with negation (~), but I couldn't get that to work either, so I'm going slightly mad...

Desired output:

```
GMC1    GMC2    Provider1
5       5           103
8       8           160
8       8           567
9       9           450
```

I hope this makes sense, but I'm very happy to clarify further if needed.

Many thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Can you share the desired output you want

Answer (score 2):

Merge is correct, but I think you want `how="left"`. Then you can query the merge:

```
(dataframe1.merge(dataframe2, left_on='GMC1', right_on='GMC2',
                  how='left')
           .query('Provider1 != Provider2')
)
```

Output:

```
   GMC1  Provider1  GMC2  Provider2
1     3        102   NaN        NaN
2     5        103   5.0      150.0
4     8        160   8.0        NaN
5     9        450   9.0      340.0
6     8        567   8.0        NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can query the merge like this I think:

```
mergeDF.loc[~((mergeDF["GMC1"] == mergeDF["GMC2"]) & (mergeDF["Provider1"]==mergeDF["Provider2"]))]
```

```
  GMC1 GMC2 Provider1 Provider2
1   5   5    103       150.0
3   8   8    160       NaN
4   8   8    567       NaN
5   9   9    450       340.0
```